# Pinto Beans Plant - Leaves turning yellow , wilting at bottoms , translucent holes

Tags: wilt, beans

[image: pale leaves , with translucent hole , and strange dark spot , bottoms of leaves curling , and darkening .]

[image: I]

---

Recently I've noticed translucent spots in my leaves . This plant is roughly 1-2 months old . It is a pinto bean plant , it was grown from seed . It started growing inside a paper towel , and was unfortunately exposed to some mold . However it was quickly removed , and planted into a small jar to begin growing . And it was doing fine after it had been removed .
It hasn't been exposed to outside , and has been an indoor plant it's entire life .

I just transferred it out of the small starting container today , into a larger glass container , as I had noticed the roots had grown far too deep for the container . I have a feeling this was a part of the problem . But unfortunately I'm not well versed in pinto bean plants .
The leaves have begun to yellow , and speckle , and curl at the bottoms as well as darken from the bottom up .

I have transfered it into a bigger container , and it is now in sun , as opposed to the less well lit spot it had been previously .

Is there anything else I can do to help Mr. Beanie ?

Answer (score 1):

Beans like full sun throughout their life span with constantly moist but not wet soil for the roots. Wet soil while actively growing means the root hairs cannot access oxygen in the soil pores which can result in effects on leaves which either die off or show spot effects. It's quite rare for a bean plant not to show some evidence of tough times, but they soon recover if the conditions return to normal.

Make sure the roots are never waterlogged, that your new container can drain freely, only water when it needs it, and allow the plant time to adjust to full sun. It is clear from your pictures that has been in lower light than it would like and as the stronger light hits those they will hurt a bit. However hang in there and focus on keeping new growth coming. Clip off the parts that lose their green colour.